# Elasticsearch aggregation: need Empty bucket in aggregation when the array is empty

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, bucket

I need to get buckets from empty arrays as well. I have this aggregation:

```
POST requisitions_dmb_v1_1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "__nested_field": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "locations"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "__group_by_field": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "locations.city.name",
            "missing": "__EMPTY_ARRAY_",
            "min_doc_count": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But as a result, doc_count in "key" : "_*EMPTY_ARRAY*" is always 0, but it should be equal to 5, since 5 documents have an empty array of locations:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 7,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "__nested_field" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "__group_by_field" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "New-York City",
            "doc_count" : 2
          },
          {
            "key" : "__EMPTY_ARRAY_",
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indices:

```
locations: {
  type: 'nested'
}
```

Please, can you help me make it so that I get empty buckets when the array simply has no values?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean `locations` is the empty array or `locations.city.name`? Your query would only work if the latter is true, otherwise it won't.